# What does getting an S rank accomplish?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

In all the missions I've done up to now, the S-rank method is different from what is needed to accomplish all the optional objectives. If I choose to one, I cannot have the other.

Getting the optional objectives has its perks and I was wondering what getting an S-rank will accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

The Rank you get primarily impacts the GMP (Gross Military Product) you receive. I created a small table that shows the different ranks, their scores and their bonus.

```
Rank    Score     Bonus
S       130,000   20%
A       100,000   18%
B       60,000    20%
C       30,000    30%
D       10,000    45%
E      <10,000    100%
```

This means that if you have a score of 130 000 you'd get a GMP of 26000 (130000*0.2) while having a score o 10000 would net you 4 500 (10000*0.45) and 9999 translate to 9999 (9999*1). This boosts you if you are performing bad yet places quite a limitation on the GMP you receive.

Of course there also is the fact that there are Achievements for acquiring S-Rank, but those don't really have much impact on the game.

Comment: There are also Challenges for achieving S-Rank in each mission, which give in-game rewards, unlike Achievements. (You must be connected to the online service to access Challenges.) As an example, one rewards from an S-Rank challenge was three A+-ranked soldiers.